# How to adjust subplots spacing and to place y labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I have to use matplotlib to produce the following layout.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 0], 1, 1 )
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 1], 1, 1 )
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 2], 1, 3 )
```

[image]
I'd like to add some space between second and third columns to **place a common ylabel** indicated by the red marker. I got stuck at this point. Anyone can give me some guidance? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your label is not long, you can simply add it to the middle graph and use `tight_layout` to format it:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 0], 1, 1 )
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 1], 1, 1 ) 
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 2], 1, 3 )
    if i == 1:
        ax.set_ylabel("label for all")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This will not work for very long labels, though, because `tight_layout` will misinterpret the height of the middle row. In this case, we can simply replace the text with the longer version afterwards:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 0], 1, 1 )
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 1], 1, 1 ) 
for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3, 5), [i, 2], 1, 3 )
    if i == 1:
        mylabel = ax.set_ylabel("dummy")

plt.tight_layout()

mylabel.set_text("not a dummy any more but a very very very loooooooooooooooooong label")
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]